# Qual a estrutura de banco de dados devo usar para um processo (business rules) que é dinâmico?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Quando estamos desenvolvendo um software sempre nos deparamos com essa pergunta: "Um software é forjado pelos processos ou os processos são forjados pelo sofwtare? Ou os dois?"

Estudo de Caso -

Trabalho numa companhia onde as regras de negócios não são tão bem estabelecidas, ou são muito flexiveis e muda a todo tempo. Pelo menos 3 vezes ao ano. Temos cerca de 14 usertypes nas nossas regras de negócio, mas por conta da flexibilidade o usertype3, por exemplo, que tinha alguns privilégios de acesso a páginas do sistema e a partes específicas dessas páginas, repentinamente pode assumir os privilégios do usertype8 e ter acesso a páginas que ele nao poderia acessar previamente. O pior cenário é quando se muda permissão desse usuário para uma determinda página mas que essa página precisava de informações de páginas precedentes que ele não acessava ou não acessa.

O software foi desenvolvido ha uns 5 anos e durante esse tempo, todos os remendos foram feitos de maneira caótica no sistema, de modo que hoje os diferentes usuários com as suas especificidades estão registrados entre as cerca de 800 páginas de código php. Chegou-se ao ponto da insustentabilidade onde a manutenção está se tornando inviável, e as gambiarras estão por toda parte, e tbm no (nos) banco de dados.

Então a prioridade deste ano é a reestruturação do sistema e ontem a discussão foi sobre a base de dados. Qual deveria ser o modelo ideal para suportar essa flexibilidade de regras de negócio?

A requisição básica do gerente de projetos é que **tem que ser um modelo que comporte infinitos usertypes e que necessite o mínimo de manutenção possível**.

**Modelo - 1**

Bom, com essa regra onde não existe regras estabelecidas eu fiquei meio perdido e coloco em dúvida a operacionalidade de um sistema como esse. Mas, mesmo assim fiz algumas pesquisas e montei um modelo que talvez resolva o problema de acesso às infinitas páginas por infinitos tipos de usuários. Esse modelo é auto explicativo. A palavra `adm` que coloque em cada tabela é somente para marcar tabelas de administração do sistema. As tablelas objeto, fazem referencia a objetos dentro da página. Objetos que apresentam conteúdo e comportamento baseado em critérios previamente ou futuramente definidos. A tabela `tblcontacts` é onde estão os usuários do sistema, dados com login, password etc.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo - 2**

O fato é que esse meu modelo não foi o aceito pelo grupo. O modelo que foi aceito é uma tabela (somente uma tabela - `tblAccessLevel`) onde as colunas são as possíveis páginas do sistema e as linhas todos usuários do sistema. Não haverá mais usertypes e sim níveis de acesso. Os **níveis pode ser de 0 a infinito**. Até o momento temos cerca de 20000 usuários e 800 páginas. Ou seja, **HOJE** seria uma tabela de 20.000 X 800 (até o momento). Exemplificando, cada usuário terá nível-0, para página-1 ou nível-7 para página-50, etc..., onde nível 0 é usuário não autorizado.

Eu achei meio estranha essa solução mas não descarto a possibilidade de ser a correta e por isso queria ouvir do grupo o que vcs acham e de acordo com experiencia de cada um, como seria a manutenção de sistema baseado na segunda idéia. E tbm queria ver críticas à minha solução Modelo - 1. Tbm queria saber se existe algum modelo que já seja usado no mercado com a mesma idéia.

Comment: Qual RAD ou linguagem voces utilizam? Talvez vcs estejam amarrados as limitacoes dos bancos de dados relacionais, enquanto uma regra de negocios orientada a objetos teria uma serie de vantagens. Neste caso vcs podem usar um banco de dados ou sistema de arquivos para armazenar os objetos em disco. Lembrando que determinados SGBD também implementam heranças e usertypes. De uma olhada tambem em uma topologia orientada a documentos, como por exemplo MongoDB. E´ isso, se vc compartilhar mais informaçoes, como linguagem, SGDB e um estudo de caso/problema tipico podemos conversar mais.

Comment: Oi Ricardo, a linguagem é php e o banco é Mysql. O projeto é muito grande. Hoje existem cerca de 170 tabelas no banco e dados. Acho que seria muito trabalhoso passar tudo isso para uma arquitetura orientada a documentos.